# How can i solve an undefined method error

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

my laravel 9.1 is getting error:

```
public function index()
    {
  $fingers = fingerprint:: latest()->paginate(15);
return view('crud.fliste', compact('fingers'))
      ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 15);
      }
    public function create()
    {
      return view('crud.fekle');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $request->validate(['kisiadi' => 'required']);
        fingerprint::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('fingerprint.index')
            ->with('success', 'parmak izi ekleme işlemi başarılı.');
```

i am trying something, but i cannot solve this. I tried something; i deleted "{,}", i edited syntax but i am still geting error. can you guys help me?

Comment: you need to provide the actual error message ... 'undefined method ....' what method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the curly brace. Please check the following code below:

```
  public function index(){
    $fingers = fingerprint:: latest()->paginate(15);
    return view('crud.fliste', compact('fingers'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 15);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('crud.fekle');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['kisiadi' => 'required']);
    fingerprint::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('fingerprint.index')->with('success', 'parmak izi ekleme işlemi başarılı.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the closing curly brace in the `store()` method?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['kisiadi' => 'required']);
    fingerprint::create($request->all());
    
    return redirect()->route('fingerprint.index')
        ->with('success', 'parmak izi ekleme işlemi başarılı.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after  solving it, only one problem left, my controller isn't defining "$id" variable. Can you guys help me again?

Comment: You could have marked my answer as your solution ;) For your your $id issue, please ask another question with more details.